# Any alternatives to Spiderable?

Tags: meteor, seo, metadata

Our version of Meteor is 0.8.1, which means it crashes when we try to install the current version of Spiderable.
PhantomJS has something to do with this incompatibility because it has some outdated dependencies, mainly the issues are about BlazeLayout and IronRouter.

However we do need the meta data to work, especially on Facebook. 
And by that I mean stuff like og:title, og:image, og:description...

Since we put the tag `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` on top of , browsers can actually read all that is inside the , but Facebook and Google won't.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Spiderable shouldn't have anything to do with BlazeLayout and IronRouter. Can you post the full error log?

Comment: There is no full error log in this case. Because when I install spiderable, it needs me to install phantomjs, and it has dependencies that causes the update of the iron router version and other packages that have issues with this new meteor version.
What I need my friend, is to show meta data without spiderable if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the [inject-initial](https://github.com/gadicc/meteor-inject-initial/) package.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Inject.rawHead('fragment', '<meta name="fragment" content="!">');
  Inject.rawHead('fragment2', '<meta name="fragment2" content="!">');
}
```

Or if you only need to set the `content` and `id` attributes, you could use `Inject.meta`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is what we have done:
 - We've installed phantomjs
 - We've installed spiderable
And let those guys update all packages they wanted to. Then, we started to force the packages versions that we know that works fine, one by one.

Thanks for all the help... now I need to learn how to use spiderable with Iron-Router :) but that is another question.